# Warning: include(PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, include, xampp, phpexcel, include-path

Im trying to implement [Converting single sheet in an XLS file to CSV with PHPExcel - Memory exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530302/converting-single-sheet-in-an-xls-file-to-csv-with-phpexcel-memory-exhausted) but got stuck in the PHP Excel loading process.

I downloaded the pack (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and, following the install instructions, copied the folder 'Classes' to three directories:

1) C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode - just my current working directory

2) C:\xampp\php\pear - bcs its what i get when I `echo get_include_path();`

and

3) C:\xampp\php\pear\PEAR - you know, just in case...

still when I run:

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```

I get the following error messages:

> Warning: include(PHPExcel.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\paths.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPExcel.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\paths.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include(PHPExcel/IOFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\paths.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\paths.php on line 6

tks in advance...

Comment: Then, make sure all files are in their proper folders and the paths are correct. I've used that library before and had no problem using it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tks, this is a bit new to me. isn't it just copying the folder 'Classes' in `C:\xampp\php\pear`? How do I make sure?

Comment: I ran it from a hosted server. I couldn't say for sure for a `local machine`. See what Phil posted below. Also make sure that the folder(s) names are correctly spelled, letter-case is important. `classes` is not the same as `Classes` on some servers (Unix & Windows are 2 different animals altogether)

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *...copied the folder 'Classes' to three directories*

Seems the hint is right there. Shouldn't it be

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
```

Alternatively, add the `Classes` folder to your include path...

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/Classes'), // assuming Classes is in the same directory as this script
    get_include_path()
]));

require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
```

Comment: for the next guys with the same problem, the fix is `include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';`.

Comment: Another "Happy Ending"

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

In my case i juste had to replace my

```
include "../classes/Projects.php";
```

by this:

```
require_once "./classes/Projects.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you are including files it is going to be relative to the file you are calling the `include` from.  Make sure you are looking in the correct directory.  I say this because the way you include files seems as if the PHPExcel files should be in the exact same directory, but it looks like you put this into a folder called `classes`.

For example, if your directory structure looks like this:

```
C:\
   - xampp\
       - htdocs\
           - mycode\
               - classes\  (where you extracted your files to...)
                   - (more files and subdirectories in here)
               - index.php (where you are including file into...)
```

Then you are including from where `index.php` is located.  So if PHPExcel is located in the `classes` folder, then your `include` statement should look like this:

`include classes/PHPExcel.php` or `include classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php`

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

this module worked for me initially. but then I added Yii2 and spent a long time looking for a solution to the problem. for those who find this topic, as I did and also added Yii2 to Yii1, I will leave this solution.

for me first helped this.

```
        spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
```

when i added Yii2 i changed

```
        spl_autoload_unregister(['Yii', 'autoload']);
        spl_autoload_unregister(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        require_once Yii::app()->params['rootPath'] . '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        spl_autoload_register(['YiiBase', 'autoload']);
        spl_autoload_register(['Yii', 'autoload']);
```

next use

```
  $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
  ...
  $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```